# ansible two variables substitution in with items in a task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to achieve a task like below where
{{ snapshot_id }} is registed in varaible. (it register snapshot id of 3 or more snapshot id)

instance id is another varable whose value is read from inventory

I would like to pass varailes like below in a tasks

snapshot_id[0]  ---> groups['webA']

snapthot_id[1] ----> groups['webb']

```
 ec2_vol:
        snapshot: "{{ snapshot_id }}"
        instance: "{{ hostvars[item]['instance_id'] }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        device_name: /dev/sda1
     register: volume_id
     with_items:
         - {{ snapshot_id[0], groups['webA'] }}
         - {{ snapshot_id[1], groups['webB']    }}
         - {{ }}
         - {{ }}
```

What would be the right syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Using [with_together](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) you can come up with somthing like this:

```
 ec2_vol:
        snapshot: "{{ item.0}}"
        instance: "{{ hostvars[item.1]['instance_id'] }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        device_name: /dev/sda1
     register: volume_id
     with_together:
         - {{ snapshot_id }}
         - {{ [ groups['webA'], groups['webB'] ] }}
```

Im not quite sure where are you heading with the `group` vars but that should satisfy your need.